# Execute a php function with field value after it has been entered

Tags: php, ajax

I have a form that ask the email of the new user. I got a php function that can use this email to get informations (firstname, lastname, office, job...) using a cURL request and return it into an array (`$full_informations`).

**I want this function to be executed after an email has been entered**. For different reasons, I cannot directly add code to my form, so I need something can be read somewhere else in the body or the head.

I got this field that is automatically populated by a script:

```
<input  onKeyPress="" class="editingSize " type="text" id="emails" name="emails" size="" value="" maxlength="150">
```

I want to be able to send the value of this field to a php function such as

```
$full_informations = get_more_info_from_mail($email)
```

then I could do something like

```
$firstname = $full_informations['firstname'];
$lastname = $full_informations['lastname'];
$job = $full_informations['job'];
//...
```

and make these variables automatically inserted in my mysql DB without asking the user to complete the form (I know how to make that part).

So, again, my question is, **how can I get my function to be called with the value of the field after the user has entered an email**?

I suppose I'll need some ajax request but I'm not familiar with those at all.

Comment: no. you cannot call php functions from html/javascript. You MUST use an ajax call to invoke a server-side php script, which can then call your php function.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for the hint. I'll remember that.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#emails').on('blur',function() {
        $.post('/path/to/your/php.php',
        {email: $('#emails').val()},
        function(json) {
            alert('responded with '+json.response);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Your php script should look like this:

```
<?php
$email = $_GET['email'];
// make sure you verify the email is in a correct format.
// save it to a database

//if it succeeds:
echo json_encode(array('response'=>'success'));

//if it fails:
echo json_encode(array('response'=>'failure'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm just wondering now how can I refer to the returned result?

I'm use to do it using php that would look like
`$full_informations = get_more_info_from_mail($email)`
then I could use the `$full_informations` array that is returned my function. What can I use that is returned to complete my php script? I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Thanks the fast update. I tried it but it alerted me 'responded with undefined'. Any clue why this happen?

Comment: Sorry, the array keys in php need quote marks. Updated again.

Comment: It still says 'responded with undefined'. I might add that it always echo: {"response":"success"}{"response":"failure"

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a mysql database. You can achieve this in php like this:

Put this at the beginning of you page

```
<?
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
        $mail = $_POST['mail'];
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $mail");
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

        $firstName = $row[0]; //FirstName
        $lastName =  $row[1]; //LastName
        $job =       $row[2]; //Job
    }
?>
```

You html should look like this:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="mail" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For my purpose, I believe that ajax is the only suitable way. However, I believe that this solution could work well in other circonstances. Thanks for sharing.